# Maven - how to verify that dependencies compiled with specific Java level (1.7 for example)?

Tags: maven, maven-3

For example, Java Maven project have ben compiled with [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) with target level 1.7 **have number of dependencies**.

How to verify that those dependencies compiled with some specific Java target level as well (1.7 for example)?

Comment: Unclear. What do you want to check precisely? That the dependencies were compiled using Java 7? That they are compatible with Java 7?

Comment: To check the version of dependencies i would suggest to use an maven-enforcer rule like this one: http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html

Comment: @Tunaki yes, that they were compiled using Java 7.

Comment: @khmarbaise looks like exactly what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, i have used [Extra Enforcer Rules](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/) as additional dependency to [Maven enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) that provides extra rules, as a solution.

The usage of this functionality described [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html), and specifically in my code it looks like that:

```
   <properties>
        <extra-enforcer-rules>1.0-beta-4</extra-enforcer-rules>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>${extra-enforcer-rules}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <executions>   
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                                        <maxJdkVersion>1.7</maxJdkVersion>   
                                    </enforceBytecodeVersion>
                                </rules>
                                <fail>true</fail>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
                            <version>${extra-enforcer-rules}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>        
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```